# Trying to get txn hash

Tags: transactions, erc-20, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

How can I get an Ethereum transaction hash whenever a particular **NFT/ERC20 token** is transferred? Not sure exactly what process/code is needed to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a WebSocket from a node provider to track the `transfer` event that all ERC-20 and ERC-721/1155 smart contracts emit when there is a token transfer.

Check this example in ethers v6:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
const ABI = require("./abi.json"); //ABI of the smart contract
require("dotenv").config();

async function getTransfer(){
    const usdcAddress = "SMART_CONTRACT_ADDRESS"; 
    const provider = new ethers.WebSocketProvider(`WEBSOCKET_URL`);

    const contract = new ethers.Contract(usdcAddress, ABI, provider);

    contract.on("Transfer", (from, to, value, event)=>{

        let transferEvent ={
            from: from,
            to: to,
            value: value,
            eventData: event,
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(transferEvent, null, 4))

    })
}

getTransfer()
```

But with this, you'll have to manage filters for each token, and if you miss a filter change, it's gone.

**Another way to track this is by using [QuickAlerts](https://www.quicknode.com/quickalerts)**, an on-chain alerting tool; you can set up an alert whenever a token is transferred. QuickAlerts not just makes event tracking easier but also has retry logic built-in so if you miss an alert it'll retry to send that alert multiple times.

A QuickAlerts expression to track token transfers would look like this:

```
(tx_logs_address == 'SMART_CONTRACT_ADDRESS') && (tx_logs_topic0 == '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef') && (tx_logs_topic3_int > 0)
```

In QuickAlerts, you can create custom expressions to place a custom WebHook on-chain. In the above example, we are using `tx_logts_address` variable to catch transaction logs for a particular address. SMART_CONTRACT_ADDRESS needs to be replaced with the address of the token smart contract. `tx_logs_topic0` will filter the transactions which match the particular event type, here `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef` is the hash form of the `Transfer` event and `tx_logs_topic3_int > 0` simply means that all the token above 0 token id.

Some QuickAlerts Resources:

- Docs: https://www.quicknode.com/docs/quickalerts/getting-started
- Getting Started Video: https://youtu.be/Y3UZDxX-ZD8
- Written Guides:

  - Overview of QuickAlerts: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/quicknode-products/quickalerts/an-overview-of-quicknodes-quickalerts
  - Understanding QuickAlerts expressions: https://www.quicknode.com/guides/quicknode-products/quickalerts/tracking-blockchain-event-data-with-quicknodes-quickalerts-expressions

Answer (score 1):

You should look into events.

ERC20/721 both emit an event on transfer. When listening at them, you can retrieve the transaction hash from that.

using ethersv6

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);
const eventName = 'Transfer';
const eventFilter = contract.filters[eventName]();

contract.on(eventFilter, async (eventData) => { 
  //do something with the eventData
})
```